# how to multiply each element of A as a scalar to B

Tags: matlab, octave

given a vector and matrix A and B, how to multiply each element of A as a scalar to B then add up each of the new matrix, without using a for loop.

What i mean is:

```
A = [1;2;3]
B = [1 2;3 4 ;5 6] 

C = (A(1) * B) + (A(2) * B) + (A(3) * B)

ans =

 6    12
18    24
30    36

C = sum(C)
C =

54    72
```

but I can't do it manually because the vector is too long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following command:

```
sum(reshape(sum(B(:)*A.',2),size(B)))
```

**Explanation:**

```
B(:)*A'
```

Flatten out `B` and multiply each element of it with each element of `A`.

```
sum(B(:)*A.',2)
```

Sum across the 'A' dimension (rows).

```
reshape(sum(B(:)*A.',2),size(B))
```

Reshape to get back to the original dimensions of `B`.

```
sum(reshape(sum(B(:)*A.',2),size(B)))
```

Sum across the columns as you wanted.

---

**Edit**

Suggestion from @verbatros which work when `A` is row vector as well:

```
sum(reshape(sum(B(:)*A(:).',2),size(B)))
```

Comment: You might want to change the expression to sum(reshape(sum(B(:)*A(:).',2),size(B))), which works when A is either a row or column vector.

Comment: @verbatross I edited the answer with your suggestion.

Comment: why so compilcated? Make a step back and recognise that you can first build the sum and then multiply

Answer (score 1):

Very easy:

```
A = [1;2;3]
B = [1 2;3 4 ;5 6]

C = sum (A(:)) .* sum (B)
C =

   54   72
```